# Drupal 6 - Theme custom search form results

Tags: theming, search

I have a **custom search form** written in my custom-module. On submit, i have used do_search api and then I have made some modifications/customization with the results.

Now having my customized results, how can I render them?

**Work so far**--->

- In **custom-module.module**

  ```
  function custom_module_search_ticket_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
     // do_search()
     //  customizations (in the sense, removed few results according to my requirements. Otherwise the result-object/array format is same as of core search results) 

      return theme('rootcandy_my_search_results', $results, $type);
  }

  function custom_module_theme() {
    return array(
      'rootcandy_my_search_result' => array(
        'arguments' => array('result' => NULL, 'type' => NULL),
        'template' => 'rootcandy-my-search-result',
      ),
      'rootcandy_my_search_results' => array(
        'arguments' => array('results' => NULL, 'type' => NULL),
        'template' => 'rootcandy-my-search-results',
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- Rootcandy is the theme I have used. In rootcandy's **template.php**

  ```
  function rootcandy_preprocess_rootcandy_my_search_results (&$vars)  {
    // copied lines from core search module's search.pages.inc function template_preprocess_search_results(&$vars)
  }

  function rootcandy_preprocess_rootcandy_my_search_result (&$vars) {
    // copied lines from core search module's search.pages.inc function template_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) 
  }
  ```
- Under rootcandy theme folder, **Added below tpl.php files**

  ```
  rootcandy-my-search-results.tpl.php  (copied from core search's search-results.tpl.php)
  rootcandy-my-search-result.tpl.php   (copied from core search's search-result.tpl.php)
  ```

Now I have done this much, clearing cache, after everything; Submitting my custom-search-form renders nothing, other than the form. When I print my customized results, they are fine. Theming part is not working.

Where is the mistake? Plz help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever u have done so far is correct. Only thing left now is to render the content from ur preprocess 'rootcandy_preprocess_rootcandy_my_search_results' to ur 'rootcandy-my-search-results.tpl.php'. U have to start debugging in this way.

1. Check ur $vars['form'] contains ur form values in  'rootcandy_preprocess_rootcandy_my_search_results'
2. create a variable in preprocess and try using it in ur rootcandy-my-search-results.tpl.php.
   Eg: $vars['testing'] = "this is to confirm that variable is working in rootcandy-my-search-results.tpl.php"
3. if you print $testing in ur rootcandy-my-search-results.tpl.php and it gives "this is to confirm that variable is working in rootcandy-my-search-results.tpl.php" Which means its working fine.
4. Then you can pass ur form results to the tpl file. 
   Eg: $vars['result'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['result']);

Try this. Ur first goal will be making sure u can get ur preprocess values in ur tpl file.

Comment: please don't add short form like "u", "ur". add it in full form.